# Is there a way to find which font has been rendered by Phonegap?

Tags: html, css, cordova, fonts

Our UX team raised a few defects saying that wrong fonts have been used on some of the Phonegap pages.

Looking into the code, we have specified multiple options in the font-family, like so:

```
font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,arial,san-serif;
```

Is there a way to find which font has been rendered?

I know that Google chrome and Firefox can natively tell which font has been rendered and there are extensions for desktop safari and there is http://whatfontapp.com/ app to tell which font has been used in mobile safari. But none of it seems to be working with Phonegap pages.

Is there any trick other developers are using to find exactly which font has been rendered.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i debug a working version of the app

- Debug version of the apk on your phone, i.e you ran `cordova run android`.
- You have developer tools set up correctly
- Your phone is paired correctly with your computer.
- You have all the correct sdks (including the emulation via usb)

While plugged into your computer open up the debug version of the app.
navigate in your browser to `chrome://inspect/#devices`

If your phone is set up correctly you should see your device listed and inspectable.

Click inspect and you will see your app in your browser.

You can check out all your scripts and inspect everything including css.

Google suggest using chrome canary for debugging.

Hope it helps!